# How can I edit python files in heroku?

Tags: heroku

I am using Heroku to run a Python telegram bot with Heroku Postgres as DB. I wanted to edit a Python file in my app so how can I do it? Is there any live text editor I can use to edit my file?
Thanks.

Comment: How did you deploy the bot? Did you deploy the bot manually via git? Then you will have to checkout the heroku git repo, put your changes there, commit and push them to Heroku. If you deployed it via a Heroku Button you will need to checkout the GitHub repo first, add Heroku's git remote and do the mentioned steps above.

Comment: I did using the Heroku button so does that mean I need to make the necessary changes in the repo itself?
Sorry I didn't understand much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `git` installed on your CLI.

Clone the git repo from GitHub (the following git url is just an example)

```
git clone https://github.com/NNTin/discord-twitter-bot.git
```

Go to Heroku settings. There you will find a Heroku git URL. Add the Heroku remote.

```
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/[yourappname].git
```

Do your code changes with your editor of choice. Version and commit your changes

```
git add .
git commit -m "a helpful commit message to know what you have done in the past"
```

Push the changes to your heroku remote

```
git push heroku master
```

Comment: Hey there, I have a question: There's just 1 file I need to update and not the whole app. How can I add only 1 file?

Comment: You can add individual files with `git add` but only after you have checked out the app.

Comment: Yes, my whole app is running already, so I just do
`git add filename`
to add it?

Comment: "checked out" is a phrase used in `git` context. It does not mean the app is running. You have to do all the steps I listed in my answer.

Comment: The `git add .` adds all the files so my data will also be affected if I push all my files without the tokens and other configuration data, right?

Comment: `.` adds everything. To add individual files you name them specifically.

Comment: My push gets rejected because I don't have a heroku.yml file but that file is actually in the main directory and not the directory in which the file is changed. I cannot do `git push heroku master`

Comment: You didn't clone from the GitHub repo.